# What are the appropriate terms for "Current", "Previous" and "Previous of Previous" in a workers' compensation context?

Tags: word-choice, terminology

I am trying to find the appropriate header labels instead of "Current", "Previous" and "Previous of Previous" in a spreadsheet. For example:

```
EmployeeID | Compensation | Previous Compensation (1) | Previous Compensation (2)

ssmith374  | $45,983      | $43,436                   | $40,176

hbrown394  | $37,736      | $36,154                   | $34,643

Wgold872   | $67,734      | $64,232                   | $62,433
```

Is there any appropriate terminology or better terms to use in this context?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider *Current, Prior, Next Prior*

Answer (score 0):

I would use 
*Current*, *Prior*, *Previous*.

Or 
*Current*, *Immediately Prior*, *Previous*.

Answer (score -1):

You can consider Existing, Pre-existing and Initial

Comment: **Initial** will stop being *¨previous of previous¨* after just two iterations.  And some explanation would improve your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I would use "Compensation in Previous Employment." Though long, it makes clear the distinction with "Previous Compensation" while retaining the words "compensation" and "previous."